# onclick on link display only div, make other body balck or shaded

Tags: html, tags, toggle, lightbox, blur

I have a page which has anchor tag clicking on which ma div tag toggles. I want to make whole body of page black or shaded except that Div tag.

Answer (score 0):

Well then you need to set body's background color first and then your div's background. So make function `toggle` which would check for presence of class in both elements and then ether add or remove class attribute (for both elements) with `$('#mydiv').addClass('foo')` or `$('#mydiv').removeClass('foo')`. Then you can use CSS to declare background colors for body and then div: add class - color in, remove class - color out

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you really want a "Modal Dialog" type of display.  There are a number of JQuery and other methods to do this.

Here is a good one that I've used before, [Simple Modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)